# Using ng-template reference in ngSwitch

Tags: angular

Instead of writing the `html` code in each `*ngSwitchCase` block, I want to add a reference to a `ng-template`
took the idea from this (from angular docs):

```
<div *ngIf="show; then thenBlock; else elseBlock">this is ignored</div>
<ng-template #primaryBlock>Primary text to show</ng-template>
```

want to do this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="switchVar">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1; then myTemplate"></div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>output2</div>
</div>
<ng-template #myTemplate>HTML TEXT</ng-template>
```

instead of this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="switchVar">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1">HTML TEXT</div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>output2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't use template blocks with `ngSwitch`. Out of curiosity... for what do you need this?

Comment: Instead of writing a lot of html in every ngSwitchCase block, and instead of creating a new component just for this piece of html, I thought creating ng-templates and refer to them in the ngSwitchCase block

Comment: There is some explaination of situation with structural directives and template variables : http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/thomas/2017/05/use-angular-template-reference-variables-anywhere-in-the-template-not.html

Answer (score 10):

Can be achieved with [ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet). Second template also demonstrates ability of passing context.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="switchVar">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmplFirst"></ng-container>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmplSecondWithContext; context: {bar: 42}"></ng-container>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #tmplFirst>HTML TEXT</ng-template>
<ng-template #tmplSecondWithContext let-foo="bar">Output: {{foo}}</ng-template>
```