# Angular: Show a common template in multiple div containers

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a requirement to show same set of buttons in 2 different places in my same component. I know I can create a shared component and link that component in both the places but I want to keep the buttons code in the same component. Below is my scenario -

```html
<ng-container>
    <button>A1</button>
    <button>A2</button>
    <button>A3</button>
</ng-container>
```

Above is my common template and I want to use that inside the 2 divs **D1** & **D2** respectively.

```html
<div class="D1">
  <!-- Place the ng-container template here -->
</div>
<div class="D2">
  <!-- Place the ng-container template here -->
</div>
```

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are practical scenarios of \*ngTemplateOutlet directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908844/what-are-practical-scenarios-of-ngtemplateoutlet-directive)

Check more on [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description)

Answer (score 0):

Define your buttons within an `ng-template` block and assign it a template reference variable.

```
<ng-template #myButton>
 <button>A1</button>
 <button>A2</button>
 <button>A3</button>
</ng-template>
```

Then, you can use the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive to insert the buttons into your divs. Do this by using the `ng-container` directive and set its `ngTemplateOutlet` attribute to the template reference variable you defined.

```
<div class="D1">
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myButton"></ng-container>
</div>
<div class="D2">
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myButton"></ng-container>
</div>
```